# How to delete existing objects using a helm chart?

Tags: kubernetes-helm

We have an application that has been deployed for some time using Helm. During its lifecycle, the helm chart we use (all components are deployed from the same, single chart) created more and more objects, like

```
deployment/app-component-a
deployment/app-component-b
deployment/app-component-c
```

and so on.

Now the programmers have decided to abandon `app-component-b` and want it to be deleted when we release the next version of our application. However, I only found documentation on creating and updating Kubernetes objects with Helm; there seems to be no way to declare "I want this Kubernetes object gone" using a Helm chart.

What would be the best way (apart from doing it manually, ofc)? Unfortunately, completely removing and reinstalling the chart is currently no option for us because we have a large amount of PVCs/StatefulSets that don't have the necessary "do not purge on deletion" annotation yet.

Comment: just helm uninstall <release-name> for app-component-b

Comment: Not feasible; all components are within the same helm-chart, and, AFAIK, helm uninstall would remove all objects created by our chart.

Comment: If you delete it from the chart and `helm upgrade`, Helm will delete the single resource.

Comment: `helm upgrade` seems to work when it comes to deleting yaml object, but seems to fail if you autogenerate objects inside yaml with `range` based on values file